# Story in a Ranger Rick magazine about invasive species, told with fictional animals in an almost surreal way

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading one of my father's old Ranger Rick magazines (From before 2000 most likely) which had this story meant to teach about the danger of invasive species. It was weird, and had silly made-up animals and plants. I can't find it, but I think it was called something like "Here and There", which were the names of the two places talked about in the story. It was illustrated as well.

Comment: Wow! They still published _Ranger Rick_ into the 2000s? I read it as a kid in the 70s!

Comment: [This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20100211061752/http://www.nwf.org/Kids/Ranger-Rick/Parents-and-Educators/Meet-Ranger-Rick.aspx) (taken from the Wayback machine as it's no longer on the site) mentions *wrestling with alien species in the Florida Everglades (February 2007)*. I cannot find a copy of the Feb 2007 issue to see what exactly is being referred to.